# skip wsimport import of common xsd file inside multiple wsdl files

Tags: java, web-services, maven, xsd, wsdl

I have 10 `WSDL` files and all of them import a common domain driven `xsd` file into them.

I have created a common jar file with xjc for the common domain driven `xsd`.

I have included it as a dependency in maven project that publishes these webservices after doing wsimport of `WSDL`file

The `WSDL` import by maven still generates common domain driven xsd in target/generated-sources

My question is how can i skip the import of common xsd from wsimport of wsdl.